# String converting and parsing a few rows of a .csv file

Tags: beginner, parsing, csv, go

There are not many available resources for refactoring go code.  I'm a novice gopher who would appreciate any feedback on a small program which reads a .csv file, string converts and parses a few rows in order to perform a sub method.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

const file = "csvdata/csvtest.csv"
// what should stay in main()?  What should be refactored?
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading all lines: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(f)
    reader.Comma = ';'

    for {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Print(err)
            os.Exit(-1)
        }
        // need to refactor variables, could I use a type struct?
        var num string = (record[2])
        var name string = (record[3])
        var eia string = (record[5])
        var cia string = (record[6])
        var inc_percent = (record[7])
        var estIncTxn string = (record[8])
        var inc_diff float64
        // I would like to turn this chunk into it's own function
        for i := 0; i < len(record[i]); i++ {
            estInc, err := strconv.ParseFloat(eia, 64)
            actInc, err := strconv.ParseFloat(cia, 64)
            inc_diff = (actInc - estInc)
            if err == nil {
        //How could I turn the following into a template?
                fmt.Println("============================================================\n")
                fmt.Printf("Account: %+s - %+s exceeded the IncAmt by %+v same as $%+v\n", num, name, inc_percent, inc_diff)
                fmt.Printf("over the monthly incoming amount of $%+v. Currently, the declared\n", actInc)
                fmt.Printf("profile is established at $%+v with an expectancy of (%+v).\n", estInc, estIncTxn)
            } else {
                log.Fatalf("Error converting strings: +v", err)
            }

        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Here is a single line of the csv file.

```
30;4;102033657;COCACOLA;53764;15000.00;73010.58;387%;4;30;650%;15000.00;89558.96;497%;3;5;66%;DDA
```

Sample of the output:

> ==============================================================================
>
> Account: 102033657 - COCACOLA exceeded the IncAmt by 387% same as
>   $58010.58 over the monthly incoming amount of $73010.58. Currently,
>   the declared profile is established at $15000 with an expectancy of
>   (4).
>
> ==============================================================================

Eventually I would be capturing the outgoing amount as well for each record (just to give everyone an idea of where I'm going with this).  I'm assuming a template would be the best way to approach this situation?  How could this be refactored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is tidy up the code and fix obvious bugs. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

const file = "csvdata/csvtest.csv"

type Amounts struct {
    EstimatedAmt float64
    ActualAmt    float64
    Percent      string
    EstimatedTxn string
}

type Account struct {
    Num  string
    Name string
    In   *Amounts
    Out  *Amounts
}

const reportSeparator = "============================================================\n"

func printAccountMonth(a *Account) error {
    fmt.Printf(
        reportSeparator,
    )
    fmt.Printf(
        "Account: %+s - %+s exceeded the incoming amount by %+v, the same as $%+v\n",
        a.Num, a.Name, a.In.Percent, a.In.ActualAmt-a.In.EstimatedAmt,
    )
    fmt.Printf(
        "over the monthly incoming amount of $%+v. Currently, the declared\n",
        a.In.ActualAmt,
    )
    fmt.Printf(
        "profile is established at $%+v with an expectancy of (%+v).\n",
        a.In.EstimatedAmt, a.In.EstimatedTxn,
    )
    return nil
}

func readAmounts(r []string) (a *Amounts, err error) {
    a = new(Amounts)
    est := r[0]
    a.EstimatedAmt, err = strconv.ParseFloat(est, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error converting string: +v", err)
    }
    act := r[1]
    a.ActualAmt, err = strconv.ParseFloat(act, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error converting string: +v", err)
    }
    a.Percent = r[2]
    a.EstimatedTxn = r[3]
    return a, nil
}

func accountMonth(record []string) error {
    var err error
    var a Account
    a.Num = record[2]
    a.Name = record[3]
    a.In, err = readAmounts(record[5 : 5+6])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    a.Out, err = readAmounts(record[11 : 11+6])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = printAccountMonth(&a)
    return err
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    rdr := csv.NewReader(f)
    rdr.Comma = ';'

    for {
        record, err := rdr.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = accountMonth(record)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf(reportSeparator)
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Record:
[30 4 102033657 COCACOLA 53764 15000.00 73010.58 387% 4 30 650% 15000.00 89558.96 497% 3 5 66% DDA]
0 30
1 4
2 102033657
3 COCACOLA
4 53764
5 15000.00
6 73010.58
7 387%
8 4
9 30
10 650%
11 15000.00
12 89558.96
13 497%
14 3
15 5
16 66%
17 DDA
```

Output:

```
============================================================
Account: 102033657 - COCACOLA exceeded the incoming amount by 387%, the same as $58010.58
over the monthly incoming amount of $73010.58. Currently, the declared
profile is established at $15000 with an expectancy of (4).
============================================================
```

Obviously it needs a lot more work, but it's a start.

Comment: this is definitely more idiomatic go code.  I would upvote this answer right now but I have not been granted access.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for i := 0; i < len(record[i]); i++ {
```

... I don't think that does what you intended. It seems like just luck from how the data is that it works, or did I miss something? :-) I think you can just take the for {} loop out altogether.

I'd move the ParseFloat() calls up to where you assign the record[] values to named variables. Be sure to check the err return from both calls.

Your idea of using a struct is also good.

```
type SomeRecord struct {
    Num  int
    Name string
    Eia  float
    // etc
}
```

The for moving some of the code to a function: Have the function take a SomeRecord as a parameter and do the output.

I don't know if using a template is necessary for such a short string, but if you want to then outside of the loop read the template file with text/template, specifically [template.ParseFiles](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#ParseFiles) and then execute the template when appropriate with the record data or a new data structure if it needs data not in the record. If this is all the program does it might make most sense to have the `SomeRecord` struct have the data that the template needs (so include IncDiff).

Comment: Thanks for your observations.  Well in this case the for loop is superfluous because I only listed one record entry as a csv sample.  However, my actual file contains over several thousand records.

Comment: Actually, what I would like to do is create individual markdown files of the output for each record.  I will be adding more implementation to the current template.  What packages would you recommend I look at for this task?

Comment: I meant the second loop (`for i := 0; i < len(record[i]); i++ {` ... that doesn't seem to do anything (useful/correctly). For Markdown have a look at blackfriday: http://github.com/russross/blackfriday